# How exactly do you implement SGD with momentum?

Tags: implementation, sgd

I am looking up sources to implement SGD with momentum, but they are giving me different equations.

(`beta` is the momentum hyper-parameter, `weights[l]` is a matrix of weights for layer `l`, `gradients[l]` are the gradients for layer `l`, etc)

[This](https://deepnotes.io/sgd-momentum-adaptive) source gives:

```py
v[l] = beta*v[l] - learning_rate*gradients[l]
weights[l] = weights[l] + v[l]
```

But [this](https://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter06_optimization/momentum-scratch.html) source gives:

```py
v[l] = beta*v[l] + learning_rate*gradients[l]
weights[l] = weights[l] - v[l]
```

Are they equivalent?

Also, does it matter if `beta + learning_rate != 1`? (In this case this would be different from the exponential moving average equation, where they sum to 1).